# how to insert values in sql server through radio button

Tags: c#, winforms

I previously use this code for insert operation but along with this I want to save the radiobutton values:

```
cmd.CommandText="INSERT INTO Table1 (username,password,gender VALUES(@username,@password,gender)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textBox2.Text);
```

I have two radio buttons for male and female, I want to save only one value in the database so I have used groupbox for selecting only one radio button but how to insert into database as male or female.

I am working on windows form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use a combo box with 2 values in it, one for male and one for female and just insert the selected value. This would also take up less space on the form which may or may not be useful.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", genderCombo.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162839/how-to-transfer-the-text-from-dynamically-generated-user-control-to-a-textbox
CAN YOU HELP ME  PLEASE

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
cmd.CommandText="INSERT INTO Table1 (username,password,gender) VALUES (@username,@password,@gender)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textBox2.Text);

if(radioMale.Checked)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", "Male");
else
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", "Female");
```

Comment: thank you sir, that was very easy, why i didint thought i dont know, i thot it would be a complex step, can you tell me can i save bool values in the sql server? what is the data type for that?

Comment: @shariq_khan you can indeed, the data type is `bit`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162839/how-to-transfer-the-text-from-dynamically-generated-user-control-to-a-textbox
CAN YOU HELP ME BHAI PLEASE

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
cmd.CommandText="INSERT INTO Table1 (username,password,gender) VALUES (@username,@password,@gender)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textBox2.Text);

if(radioMale.Checked)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", "Male");
else
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", "Female");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private string selectedValue, date;
        private int i;
        private SqlCommand xcmd;
        private SqlConnection xcon;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                day_DropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("DD", "DD"));
                month_DropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("MM", "MM"));
                year_DropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("YY", "YY"));
                for (i = 1; i < 32; i++)
                {
                    day_DropDownList.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                }
                for (i = 1; i < 13; i++)
                {
                    month_DropDownList.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                }
                for (i = 1950; i < 2014; i++)
                {
                    year_DropDownList.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                }
                employeeName_Txt.Focus();
            }


        }



        protected void submit_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            selectedValue = gender_RadioButtonList.SelectedValue;

            xcon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; DataBase=AptechDB; UID=sa; Password=123;");

            xcon.Open();
            date = day_DropDownList.Text.ToString() + "/" + month_DropDownList.Text.ToString() + "/" + year_DropDownList.Text.ToString();
            xcmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblEmployee values('" + employeeName_Txt.Text + "','" + date + "','" + selectedValue + "','" + post_Txt.Text + "','" + city_Txt.Text + "','" + country_Txt.Text + "','" + mobileno_Txt.Text + "')", xcon);
            xcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Label1.Text = "Information submitted successfully";
            xcon.Close();
            clear();
        }

        public void clear()
        {
            employeeName_Txt.Text = "";
            day_DropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;
            month_DropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;
            year_DropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;
            post_Txt.Text = "";
            city_Txt.Text = "";
            country_Txt.Text = "";
            mobileno_Txt.Text = "";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into table1 (Name,Mail,Phone,Addres,Gender) values (@Name,@Mail,@Phone,@Addres,@Gender)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mail", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", textBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addres", textBox4.Text);
        if (radioButton1.Checked==true)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", "Male");
        else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", "Female");
```

Comment: How does this code improve on any of the previously posted answers?